# Print next line when pattern matches

Tags: bash

let say I got a file:

```
aaaaaaa
bbbbbbb
ccccccc
```

Now I want to search for bbbbbbb and when I got match, I want get result from next line which in this case is ccccccc. I was looking in grep man page and into bash internal parsing functions, but couldn't find anything related for this situation. Anyone got idea how I could achieve this ?

Thanks,

Comment: `while IFS= read -r line; do [[ $line == bbbbbbb ]] && IFS= read -r line && echo "$line"; done < file`?

Comment: What do you want when yhe second line is also `bbbbbbb` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `-A` option for `grep` -- it will list following lines. E.g.:

```
grep -A1 bbbbbbb
```

although that will list the b's and c's... so you could do:

```
grep -A1 bbbbbbb | grep -v bbbbbbb
```

to exclude the b's.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/bbbbbbb/{n;p}' file
```

Output:

```
ccccccc
```

Answer (score 1):

here's an `awk` solution that may be helpful

```
awk 'f{print;f=0} /bbbbbbb/{f=1}' file
ccccccc
```

using `grep` maybe

```
cat file | grep "bbbbbbb" -A1 | tail -n 1
ccccccc
```

Answer (score 0):

Using gawk/awk:

```
gawk '/bbbbbbb/ { getline; print $0 }' file
```